# NSComboBox with multiple selection Cocoa

Tags: cocoa, nscombobox

[image: Multiselect NSComboBox]

Can we have a NSComboBox with multiple selection through checkboxes in OSx. Please find the attached image as an example.

Please help.

Comment: Please add some clarification. Do you want to change the menu of the combo box according to the selection of a radio buttons?

Comment: @boyfarrell Thanks for replying, i have edited my question, does that helped to clarify my requirement?

Comment: I recommend using an `NSPopUpButton` configured in pull-down mode and, as the user picks item, you adjust its title to reflect what's selected.

Comment: @KenThomases But how will you show multiple selection in NSPopUpButton?

Comment: You can set the `state` of the menu items so they show a check mark.

Comment: You can add views to menu items. You can do this by making a custom view with a check box and a label and adding several of these views to the pop up buttons menu. However, this will look a bit odd on OS X as no other controls work like this on the platform. And Ken's suggestion is much simpler. A nice way to do this is with token text fields http://www.wannabegeek.com/?p=46

Comment: Thanks to all.. I have created a custom one by binding a tableview with the NSComboBox.

Answer (score 2):

According to the **NSComboBox** [class reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSComboBox_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSComboBox/objectValueOfSelectedItem) - the answer is NO.

as you can see on the ***Manipulating the Selection***:

```
@property(readonly) NSInteger indexOfSelectedItem
@property(readonly, strong) id objectValueOfSelectedItem

- deselectItemAtIndex: 
- selectItemAtIndex:
- selectItemWithObjectValue:
```

they refer to the selected item as single selection.

so I'd suggest looking for a custom solution, like keeping the selections on a different array and binding it together.

Comment: The above example is for iOS i want it for OSx

Comment: Nope, if it is "NS" -- it is macOS , not iOS